# Exponential distribution waiting time

Tags: probability

The arrival time of three buses is exponentially distributed as follows:
1. expo(2)
2.expo(5)
3. expo(10)
find the distribution of the minimum waiting time to take any bus?
what is the expected waiting time?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_i$ be the arrival time of bus $i$. Let $Z=\min(X_1,X_2,X_3)$.

Start with $P(Z>t) = P(X_1>t)P(X_2>t) P(X_3>t)$. (Do you know where this equality comes from?) From this, you should be able to recognize the distribution of $Z$ as a familiar distribution and then compute its expectation.

Comment: what is the final answer?

Answer (score 1):

The min of $n$ exponentially distributed r.v with rate $\lambda_k, k=1,...,n$ is an exponential distribution with rate = $\sum \lambda_k$. The rest is straightforward.